# Hatchback door...paint scratch...what is the best option to fix?

Tags: paint-scratches

Someone in my family opened the hatch while it was parked in the garage.  When the hatch raised up the fender hit part of the garage door assembly.  Now there are scratches (please see photo).  I think it went past the clear coat.
[image: scratches]

What is the best way to repair this?  What if I don't repair?  Will it get rusty b/c I think it went past the clear coat...and maybe even the paint.

Can I just buy some touchup paint from the manufacturer and that at least would prevent it from rusting?

**Update**
I bought some touch up paint to protect the scratch from rusting.

Answer (score 1):

If it were my car, I'd do exactly what you suggest: get some touch up paint and some touch up clear coat. That's a little scratch but it does look deep. If you catch it now, you can apply several tiny coats to fill it in. Top it off with clear coat and it won't look perfect but it won't be a rust growth point.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend treating the area with zinc (soldering acid + zinc through a 12v bandage) as shown here https://youtu.be/aJrU3scxZKc?si=gVjkPnKageB-Pot-&t=164 and only then covering it with a small layer of paint and varnish. Zinc will block the access of oxygen to the metal, the paint will protect the zinc layer from sandblasting, and the varnish will protect the paint. If there is no zinc, then there is a chance that in 3-5 years rust may appear in this place.

Any sprays with zinc work as a protective layer on the outside, but do not destroy corrosion. This is in contrast to the method of passing current through the zinc to the car body.

And all this will only work if there is a section of head metal. Otherwise, just paint and varnish will suffice.